# CodeIgniter: How to add attribute in options form_dropdown

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

from this code in codeigniter

```
$options = array(
    0  => '--Gender--',
    1  => 'Male',
    2  => 'Female',
    3  => 'Don't know',
);
echo form_dropdown('gender', $options, 0, 'class="form-control"');
```

it produce html code like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="jenis_kelamin" class="form-control">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">--Gender--</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
        <option value="3">Don't know</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

i want to make the option gender to be disabled so
how to add an attribute disabled="disabled" in the option gender ? like this code

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <select name="jenis_kelamin" class="form-control">
            <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">--Gender--</option>
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="2">Female</option>
            <option value="3">Don't know</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could use jqery for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the options like -

```
$options = array(
    '0" disabled'  => '--Gender--',
    1  => 'Male',
    2  => 'Female',
    3  => 'Don't know',
);
```

Or in this case you can also generate it manually.

Comment: One question please clarify. Giving the 0th option as disabled will render the entire select as disabled. I tried achieving this by using the firstchild selector on the select box using jquery but it gave me the entire select box disabled and it makes sense too... Since that will be the first value of the select box.

Comment: have you tried only disabled
instead of disabled="disabled"
<option value="0" selected="selected" disabled>--Gender--</option>

Answer (score 0):

create `MY_form_helper.php` in this directory: `CI_ROOT/application/helpers/MY_form_helper.php` and save this code into it:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Author: RezaAmya@gmail.com
 * Website: www.amya.ir
 */

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

if ( ! function_exists('form_dropdown'))
{
    /**
     * Drop-down Menu
     *
     * @param   mixed   $data
     * @param   mixed   $options
     * @param   mixed   $selected
     * @param   mixed   $extra
     * @param   mixed   $attr
     * @return  string
     */

    function form_dropdown($data = '', $options = array(), $selected = array(), $extra = '', $attr = array())
    {
        $defaults = array();
        if (is_array($data))
        {
            if (isset($data['selected']))
            {
                $selected = $data['selected'];
                unset($data['selected']); // select tags don't have a selected attribute
            }

            if (isset($data['options']))
            {
                $options = $data['options'];
                unset($data['options']); // select tags don't use an options attribute
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $defaults = array('name' => $data);
        }

        is_array($selected) OR $selected = array($selected);
        is_array($options) OR $options = array($options);

        // If no selected state was submitted we will attempt to set it automatically
        if (empty($selected))
        {
            if (is_array($data))
            {
                if (isset($data['name'], $_POST[$data['name']]))
                {
                    $selected = array($_POST[$data['name']]);
                }
            }
            elseif (isset($_POST[$data]))
            {
                $selected = array($_POST[$data]);
            }
        }

        $extra = _attributes_to_string($extra);

        $multiple = (count($selected) > 1 && strpos($extra, 'multiple') === FALSE) ? ' multiple="multiple"' : '';

        $form = '<select '.rtrim(_parse_form_attributes($data, $defaults)).$extra.$multiple.">\n";

        foreach ($options as $key => $val)
        {
            $attr_html = '';
            $key = (string) $key;

            if (is_array($val) && $key == 'optgroup')
            {
                if (empty($val))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                $form .= '<optgroup label="'.$val['lable']."\">\n";

                foreach ($val as $optgroup_key => $optgroup_val)
                {
                    $sel = in_array($optgroup_key, $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                    $form .= '<option value="'.html_escape($optgroup_key).'"'.$sel
                        .$attr_html.'>'
                        .(string) $optgroup_val."</option>\n";
                }

                $form .= "</optgroup>\n";
            }
            else
            {
                //manage options attributes
                if (array_key_exists($key,$attr)) {
                    if (is_array($attr[$key]))
                    {
                        foreach ($attr[$key] as $attr_name => $attr_value)
                        {
                            $attr_html .= ' '.html_escape($attr_name) .'="'.(string)$attr_value.'"'.' ';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $attr_html = $attr[$key];
                    }
                }

                $form .= '<option value="'.html_escape($key).'"'
                    .(in_array($key, $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : '')
                    .$attr_html.'>'
                    .(string) $val."</option>\n";
            }
        }

        return $form."</select>\n";
    }
}
```

```
/* Sample of usage in your code */
        $temp = 'type';
    
        $options = array(
            'val1'=>'item1',
            'val2'=>'item2'
        );
    
        $attr = array(
            'val1'=>'attr_name1="attr_value1" attr_name2="attr_value2"',
            'special'=> array(
                'attr_3'=>'attr_value3',
                'attr_4'=>'attr_value4',
                'example_attr'=>'www.amya.ir'
            )
        );
    
        $extra = array(
            'id'=> $temp,
            'class'=> "form-control show_hide"
        );
        
        echo form_dropdown($temp, $options, set_value($temp, 'val2'), $extra, $attr);
```

- please read here too: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html#setting-your-own-prefix

it should work
have fun
Reza

Comment: Maybe add a bit more explanation as to why it should work.

Comment: it only extend default **form_dropdown** function. if you set it true, it will give you new ability to send attributes for each 'option' you want. like selected, disable, data-... and any other things.

test it!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Your question helped me to develop the solution to my problem

My solution was to use jquery and select the element by tag and value on document load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('option[value$="0"]').prop("disabled", true);
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `application/helper` directory create `MY_helper.php` file and load the new helper inside the `application/autoload.php`, then add this customized `form_dropdown()` function:

```
    function my_form_dropdown($data = '', $options = array(), $selected = array(), $disabled = array(), $hidden= array(), $extra = '')
{
    $defaults = array();

    if (is_array($data))
    {
        if (isset($data['selected']))
        {
            $selected = $data['selected'];
            unset($data['selected']); // select tags don't have a selected attribute
        }

        if (isset($data['options']))
        {
            $options = $data['options'];
            unset($data['options']); // select tags don't use an options attribute
        }

        if (isset($data['disabled']))
        {
            $disabled = $data['disabled'];
            unset($data['disabled']); // select tags don't use an disabled attribute
        }

        if (isset($data['hidden']))
        {
            $hidden = $data['hidden'];
            unset($data['hidden']); // select tags don't use an hidden attribute
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $defaults = array('name' => $data);
    }

    is_array($selected) OR $selected = array($selected);
    is_array($options) OR $options = array($options);
    is_array($disabled) OR $disabled = array($disabled);
    is_array($hidden) OR $hidden = array($hidden);

    // If no selected state was submitted we will attempt to set it automatically
    if (empty($selected))
    {
        if (is_array($data))
        {
            if (isset($data['name'], $_POST[$data['name']]))
            {
                $selected = array($_POST[$data['name']]);
            }
        }
        elseif (isset($_POST[$data]))
        {
            $selected = array($_POST[$data]);
        }
    }

    $extra = _attributes_to_string($extra);

    $multiple = (count($selected) > 1 && stripos($extra, 'multiple') === FALSE) ? ' multiple="multiple"' : '';

    $form = '<select '.rtrim(_parse_form_attributes($data, $defaults)).$extra.$multiple.">\n";

    foreach ($options as $key => $val)
    {
        $key = (string) $key;

        if (is_array($val))
        {
            if (empty($val))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $form .= '<optgroup label="'.$key."\">\n";

            foreach ($val as $optgroup_key => $optgroup_val)
            {
                $sel = in_array($optgroup_key, $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                $dis = in_array($optgroup_key, $disabled) ? ' disabled' : '';
                $hid = in_array($optgroup_key, $hidden) ? ' hidden' : '';
                $form .= '<option value="'.html_escape($optgroup_key).'"'.$sel.$dis.$hid.'>'
                    .(string) $optgroup_val."</option>\n";
            }

            $form .= "</optgroup>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $form .= '<option value="'.html_escape($key).'"'
                .(in_array($key, $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''). (in_array($key, $disabled) ? ' disabled': ''). (in_array($key, $hidden) ? ' hidden': '').'>'
                .(string) $val."</option>\n";
        }
    }

    return $form."</select>\n";
}
```

The function works the same way as the core dropdown function but with new two argumets `(disabled)` and `(hidden)` where u can set an array of disabled and hidden options.

Usage of my_form_dropdown() function:

```
$data = ['name' => 'countries', class='form-control'];
$options = [
 '' => '-Select Country-',
 'burundi' => 'Burundi',
 'comoros' => 'Comoros',
 'congo' => 'D.R Congo'
];
 echo my_form_dropdown($data, $options, '', '', '');
```